# Redirect using Fetch in React

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I have the following code, where I send a POST request to an external API, which then redirects me to another page. I do not want my users to get redirected, however no matter which value of `redirect` I try, the redirection still follows... How can I avoid my users to be redirected upon sending the request?

```js
const formElement = useRef(null);

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const data = Array.from(formElement.current.elements)
            .filter((input) => input.name)
            .reduce(
                (obj, input) => Object.assign(obj, { [input.name]: input.value }),
                {}
            );

    fetch(finalFormEndpoint, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        redirect: 'manual',
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.status)
    })
}
```

Here is my form:

```html
<form action={FORM_ENDPOINT}
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            method="POST"
            ref={formElement}
        >

</form>
```

Thank you!

Comment: can you show your form component and submission logic?

Comment: @Undo Of course, done!